# Calling web services on a swing client

Tags: swing, web-services, ejb

I'm new to web service development and the ejb technology, i have developed a swing client application that has a login and registration modules, i have also developed a web application that included a package of my login and registration bean, entity classes and web services of the respective modules.

My swing client also has a web service client which i use for communication with the web app, my challenge is calling a certain action on a click of a button. i have a submit button on my registration form, so i want when i click the submit button, then all entered values be sent to the database.

Feel free to ask, your comments will be highly appreciated.

Comment: what's your concrete problem? As is, the question is too broad to be answerable here

Comment: A simple approach or examples of how i can get a swing client,ejb and web services working together.